# In IntelliJ, how can I search indexed files ONLY?

Tags: intellij-idea

It drives me absolutely nuts that IntelliJ includes non-indexed files while I search. And I don't want to create custom scopes to avoid these files, that seems unnecessary.

Is there some way of making IntelliJ **always ignore all non-indexed files when I'm searching**?

In other words, if I have done "Mark Directory as: Excluded.", I don't want its contents to appear in my search results.

I use IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.6, and with whatever settings I have, I get a lot of excluded folders in the search results (marked with grey).

Comment: What do you mean by "non-indexed files"?

Comment: Edit made, clarification added (excluded directories).

Comment: Neither Cmd-Shift-F (search in files) nor Cmd-shift-O (open file) does, here. Ignored folders are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean non project files?

Hit ctrl-n twice to toggle the option "Include Non project classes"